# Understanding the asymptotics of this function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a really nice expository paper in front of me (it deals with the computation of determinants of differential operators, however this does not feature in the question) where I got stuck with understanding the following argument regarding the asymptotic behaviour of a real valued function:

We have as $x \to \infty$, 
\begin{align}
&\frac{\sinh (\sqrt{x + \omega^2}L)}{\sinh(\sqrt x L)}\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x + \omega^2}} 
= e^{L(\sqrt{x + \omega^2)} - \sqrt x)}\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x + \omega^2}}\frac{1 - e^{-2L\sqrt{x+\omega^2}}}{1 - e^{-2L\sqrt x}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\omega^2L}{\sqrt x } + \cdots
\end{align}
(Here, $\omega$ and $L$ are constants).

I struggle to explain the last equality in my own words.
What I can see is that the middle expression tends to $1$ as $x \to \infty$, but how do I obtain the first order approximation (i.e. the second term on the right hand side). 
Is this something one should see immediately from the expression, or do I need to carefully look at Taylor series expansions and seek out this term?

Many thanks for your help!

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant term is only

$$\exp \left(L(\sqrt{x+\omega^2} - \sqrt{x})\right),$$

everything else is easily $1 + O(1/x)$. So we need to expand

$$\sqrt{x + \omega^2} - \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{\omega^2}{x}}-1\right) = \sqrt{x}\left(1 + \frac{\omega^2}{2x} + O(x^{-2}) - 1\right) = \frac{\omega^2}{2\sqrt{x}} + O(x^{-3/2}),$$

and then use

$$e^y = 1 + y + O(y^2)$$

to obtain the asymptotic

$$1 + \frac{L\omega^2}{2\sqrt{x}} + O(x^{-1}).$$

Comment: The result in question and answer cannot be (absolutely) correct because the function in the left-hand-side is an even function of $L$, and the asymptotic is not. A more detailed calculation can give the answer. (I assume that $\omega$ and $L$ are real constants.)

Comment: Ah, I tacitly assumed that $L > 0$, since that's necessary for the computation in the question to make sense. If one admits $L < 0$, then the asymptotic becomes $1 + \frac{\lvert L\rvert \omega^2}{2\sqrt{x}} + O(x^{-1})$.

Comment: Yes, absolute value is correct :-)

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes sense now. (The constant $L$ is assumed to be positive in the paper)